# Derivative of a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R $ be defined by

$f(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$. Check whether $f$ is differentiate at (0,0) or not.

I have checked that $f$ is continuous at (0,0) and both partial derivatives of $f$ exists at (0,0) and both equals to 0. But how do I check the differentiability?

Comment: Can you show that $f(x,y)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)?$

Comment: Using the [definition of differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), just evaluate the limit $$ \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

Comment: @AnginaSeng To show this limit it is enough to show that $\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{r^2})}{r}$ tends to 0 as r tends to 0, which is similar to show that $t\exp(-t^2)$ tends to 0 at t tends to infinity,which I showed by L'Hopital's rule. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you should check if
$$\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0$$
when $$(x,y) \to (0,0)$$
For this most simple, imho, is consider functions $z=x^2+y^2$ and $t=\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ and take limit on their composition.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [definition of differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), just evaluate the limit $$\begin{align} \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}&=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^{-1/(h^2+k^2)}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r}\end{align}$$

Comment: Seems just typo: in second member exponent power leaks "$-$".

Comment: @zkutch Indeed.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @mathfun  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.